# How to use parameterized build in jenkins pipeline?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I am having these lines in my Jenkinsfile:

```
   parameters {
    string(name: 'DATABASE', defaultValue: 'jenkinsdatabase', 
    description: 'The name of the database')
}

(...)
```

Now I want to use the value of ${params.DATABASE} in a step of a stage e.g.

```
sh 'mysql --user ${USER} -p${PASSWORD} --host ${HOST} -e "DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS ${params.DATABASE};CREATE DATABASE ${params.DATABASE} DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT COLLATE utf8_general_ci; commit;";export GRADLE_OPTS="-Xms1536m -Xmx1536m"'
```

But this ends with a exeception: **Bad substitution**

Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 0):

Your `sh` script body uses single quotes around it.

```
sh '...'
```

Since these are single quotes, [string interpolation](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/#_string_interpolation) will not occur. This means that all of your `$` strings will use the shell variable substitution instead of the Groovy substitution. You are getting a **Bad substitution** in the shell because the shell won't be able to substitute `${params.DATABASE}` because that is an invalid shell substitution.

`params` is a Groovy variable, so switching your single quotes to double quotes will perform string interpolation of the variables.

```
sh "..."
```